# Bit Manipulation (extract 5th bit from X and return number of 1 bits in X)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assume X is an unsigned integer how will I be able to extract the 5th bit from X and return the number of 1 bits in X. Note: these two operations don't depend on each other.

For extracting the 5th bit from X I was thinking to use the & operation to do something like this: XXXX1X & 000010

I am not really sure how to do the return the number of 1 bits in X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the number of 1-bits is relatively straightforward; you iterate over all of the bits of your number and add to some accumulator the number of bits that are set:

```
unsigned int X;     
unsigned int count; 

for (count = 0; X; X >>= 1) {
   count += X & 1;
}
```

How it works:

1. Initialize count to 0
2. Start from the MSB (most significant bit) [this is the current bit]
3. Add to count the result of the current bit & 1

   - 1 if the bit is set
   - 0 if the bit is not set
4. Shift X to the right 1 bit, so the current bit is now the next MSB
5. Repeat step 3

Extracting the 5th bit is also straightforward, simply right shift your number X by 5 and compute the logical AND with 1:

```
unsigned int fifthBit (unsigned int X) {
   return (X >> 5) & 1;
}
```

Comment: ahh I see thank you. How about extracting the 5th element? I believe I am doing this wrong I believe I might have to shift the element after I am done using the & operation.

Comment: could you explain why you move to the right instead of moving left? Is there even a difference?

Comment: There isn't really any difference, you could also shift 1 to the left 5 places `X & (1 << 5)`. I just chose to use a right shift.

Comment: Depending on the architecture `(X >> n) & 1` can be encoded in fewer or smaller instructions, since it uses _immediates_ instead of loading a constant to a register. It also works with pretty much all the types, where as `(1 << N) & uint64_t` doesn't work as planned in 32-bit architectures.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: I think doing `X & (1 << 5)` is slight fast, since `(1 << 5)` will be converted at compile time to `0x10` hence only `&` operation is needed to be done at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter and simpler way to find number of set bits in an `int` is following:

```
int num_1_bits(unsigned int x)  // or unsigned long x; or unsigned short x;
{
   int bitcount = 0;
   while(x)
   { 
      x &= (x - 1);
      ++bitcount;
   }
   return bitcount;
}
```

**How does this work?**

For an unsigned number `x`, the sequence of bits in `x - 1` will be the complement of `x` till the first set bit of `x` counted from LSB.

i.e. for `x = 20 [0b11100]`;     `x - 1 = 19 [0b11011]`
Here Bit sequence of `19` is complement of `20` till first set bit in `20` (first set bit at position 3 from LSB).

Therefore,
if you do `x & (x - 1)`, this operation will consume one set bit from `x`.

Hence,
if you want to continue doing this until `x` becomes `0`, you will need to do it as many times as there are set bits in `x`, which in turn will give you the count of set bits in `x`.

This method is better because the loop will run only as many times as there are `1` bits in `x` and hence doesn't depend on datatype of `x`.

Comment: I am not sure I would call this *simpler*, they both seem about the same *difficulty*.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, I precise that if you are looking for efficiency there are some built-in hardware instructions to perform computations on bits (counting zeros: you can deduce how many `1-bit` you have then) see this [article](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/bit-scanning-equivalencies/) as an example.